# $ Av=\lambda v \implies\ A^*v=\overline \lambda v $, Is this true only for normal operators?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

I know that is true for normal operators ( matrices). But isnt the following proof independant of normality.
$$\langle A^\ast v, v\rangle = \langle v, Av\rangle = \langle v, \lambda v\rangle = \langle \overline{\lambda} v,v\rangle $$
So we can conclude   $ A^\ast v=\overline{\lambda} $  , and we didnt use normality anywhere.

If it is true that normality isnt needed for this then also normality isnt needed for orthogonal eigenvectors either. **Where am i making a mistake ?**

---

@Omnomnomnom is the proof of $ (AB)^\ast=B^\ast A^\ast $ that goes like this 
$$ \langle (AB) v, v\rangle= \langle v, (AB)^\ast v\rangle $$
$$ \langle (AB) v, v\rangle= \langle Bv, A^\ast v\rangle= \langle v, B^\ast A^\ast v\rangle$$   also wrong becuase we cant divide by vectors
                      in inner product

Comment: I am only interested in finites spaces. So eigenvectors of an operator of different eigenvalues are orthogonal despite normality?

Comment: You did use normality implicitly in making the jump from $\langle A^* v, v \rangle = \langle \overline{\lambda} v, v \rangle $ to $A^*v  = \overline{\lambda} v$.

Comment: You can conclude that $\langle A^*v,v \rangle = \overline{\lambda}$, but this is not enough to conclude that $A^*v = \overline{\lambda}v $

Comment: can you explain why

Comment: For example, try $ A = \pmatrix{1 & 1\cr 0 & 2\cr}$, $\lambda = 2$, $v = \pmatrix{1\cr 1\cr}$.  $A^* v =  \pmatrix{1\cr 3} \ne 2 \pmatrix{1\cr 1\cr}$, but $\langle A^*v, v\rangle =  \langle 2 v, v \rangle$

Comment: $v^T A^T v= \bar \lambda v^Tv$ does not necessarily imply that $A^T v = \bar \lambda v$. It just implies that the component of $A^T v$ in the $v$ direction is the same as the component of $\bar \lambda v$ in the $v$ direction. You would need something like $w^T A^T v= \bar \lambda w^Tv$ for any $w$ to make that conclusion

Comment: @RobertIsrael I see my statment isnt true, i dont know why. It though i did the same thing as $ab=ac \Longrightarrow b=c $. Also how is normality used to make the jump you mentioned in the first comment

Comment: @MilanStojanovic $ab = ac \implies b = c$ *if you can divide by $a$*.  However, we can't simply "divide" an inner product by a vector.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom how is normality used in the proof

Comment: Your proof doesn't use normality, it's just wrong. The usual proof of this result, which would use normality, can be proven using the fact that normal operators satisfy $\|Av\| = \|A^*v\|$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom i see it is wrong. I have seen the standard proof (and i ll give it another look). But is it possible to use the proof i wrote and to use normality when  going from $\langle A^\ast v, v\rangle = \langle \overline{\lambda} v,v\rangle $ to $ A^\ast v=\overline{\lambda} $ to $ A^\ast v=\overline{\lambda} $

Comment: The usual proof of $(AB)^* = B^* A^*$ shows that $\langle (AB)^* v, w \rangle = \langle B^* A^* v, w \rangle$ for all $v,w$ from which it then follows that $(AB)^* v = B^* A^* v$, for example by substituting $w = (AB)^* v - B^* A^* v$.  That requires the freedom to choose $v$ and $w$ independently, restricting to the "diagonal" $w = v$ isn't sufficient.

Comment: The way I tend to understand the standard proof better is: choose an orthonormal basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $V$ which starts with $v / \lVert v \rVert$.  Then $[A]_{\mathcal{B}}$ is of the form $\begin{bmatrix} \lambda & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\ 0 & * & \cdots & * \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & * & \cdots & * \end{bmatrix}$.  So the $(1,1)$ entry of $A A^*$ is $|\lambda|^2 + |a_{12}|^2 + \cdots + |a_{1n}|^2$ whereas the $(1,1)$ entry of $A^* A$ is $|\lambda|^2$.  Normality then implies $a_{12} = \cdots = a_{1n} = 0$...

Comment: so the first column of $[A^*]_{\mathcal{B}}$ is $(\bar\lambda, 0, \ldots, 0)$.  I view the standard proof as just being a coordinate-free version of this argument.

Comment: @DanielSchepler i dont understand the second part of your first comment. is the proof i wrote correct?

Comment: No, it's not correct.  The point I was making is that $\langle Av, v \rangle = \langle Bv, v \rangle$ for all $v$ does not imply $A = B$.  For example, if $A$ is rotation of $\mathbb{R}^2$ by 90 degrees than $\langle Av, v \rangle = 0$ for all $v$ yet $A \ne 0$.  What *is* true is: if $\langle Av, w \rangle = \langle Bv, w \rangle$ for all $v,w$ then $A = B$.

Answer (score 4):

Normality is essential. Note that $$\begin{align*}(A^*-\overline{\lambda})^*(A^*-\overline{\lambda})&=(A-\lambda)(A^*-\overline{\lambda})\\&=AA^*-\lambda A^*-\overline{\lambda}A+|\lambda|^2\\
&=A^*A-\lambda A^*-\overline{\lambda}A+|\lambda|^2\\
&=(A^*-\overline{\lambda})(A-\lambda)\\&=(A-\lambda)^*(A-\lambda).
\end{align*}$$
This shows that if $A$ is normal, then $A-\lambda$ is also normal. Since $\|Nx\|=\|N^*x\|$ for every normal operator $N$, it also holds that $\ker N = \ker N^*$. Thus
$$
\ker (A-\lambda) = \ker(A^*-\overline{\lambda})
$$ and it follows that
$$
Av=\lambda v\ \ \ \Longleftrightarrow \ \ \ A^*v = \overline{\lambda}v.
$$

**EDIT** (Necessity of normality, 1/3/2022)

To see that the normality of $A:V \to V$ is essential, we proceed by induction on the dimension of $V$.

If $\operatorname{dim}V = 1$, $A$ being normal is trivial.

Suppose $\operatorname {dim} V >1$. By the algebraic closedness of $\mathbb C$, we can find $w \ne 0$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb C$ such that $A w = \lambda w$. By the given condition, it is straightforward to see that $A^*w = \overline{\lambda} w$, and accordingly, $\langle w\rangle^\perp \equiv \left \{ v\in V: \langle v, w\rangle = 0\right\}$ is an $A$-invariant subspace. Now by the inductive hypothesis, $B \equiv A|_{\langle w\rangle^\perp} : \langle w\rangle^\perp \to \langle w\rangle^\perp$ is normal, which implies the normality of
$$
A = \left[
\begin{matrix}
\lambda & 0 \\
0 & B
\end{matrix}
\right].
$$

Comment: Where do you show that normality is essential?

Comment: @user0 I've added a brief argument for the missing part.